# Fonts on StackExchange websites looking ugly after installing Helvectica on PC

Tags: support, design, fonts

I installed Helvetica fonts on my PC and now all Stackexchange websites look ugly!

> [image: fonts ugly]

Before them links at the top use to look very smooth and sharp! I still need Helvetica for my design work, so do not want to uninstall the fonts.

What can I do to remedy the situation? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you only installed the italics set for the font? Do you have a user stylesheet setup that overrides the site stylesheets?

Comment: This is really something on your side, nothing Stack Exchange is responsible for.

Comment: I'm not an expert in CSS at all, but if I'm not mistaken, the top-bar has this active style: `font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important`. I don't have "Helvectica" installed, so I will test it for a while. Edit: will be hard to test since it's a commercial font.

Answer (score 3):

You're right. In the end I had to go and uninstall the Helvetica font :( Now all is back to Normal, but can't use that font in Photoshop / Illustrator.

Comment: **+1** BIN HELVECTICA!!! :D

Comment: The better solution would be Userstyles: https://userstyles.org/